# How to prevent react-quill to insert a new line before list when re-loading content?

Tags: reactjs, react-quill

Using react-quill, I write a list within text, store the content into external storage, reload the content into quill: a new <br> is inserted before the list, and it happens on each reload.
Any idea what is happening, and how to prevent it?

I prepared a minimal sandbox to show the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-cookies-m5h3x
The steps to reproduce:

- write a line, followed by a bullet list
- click save to store the content to external storage
- click clear to remove all content from the editor
- click load to put the content from external storage to the editor
- BOOM! A new <br> is inserted on each save-clear-load cycle

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found [this answer by mhdhamouday](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/2905#issuecomment-683128521) in Quill GitHub Issues. This works for me.

```
var quill = new Quill('.quill', {
    theme: 'snow',
    modules: {
        toolbar : [...]
        clipboard: {
            matchVisual: false
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/2905#issuecomment-683128521 solution works very well. If you are using react component, this can be an alternative.

```
<ReactQuill
  theme="snow"
  value={block.note}
  onChange={(value) => onEditorStateChange(value, block)}
  modules={{
    clipboard: {
      matchVisual: false
    }
  }}
/>
```